# Action never fires

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have a method, which runs the action `MenuScreen` at the very end. It never fires. Why is that?

```
fun method() {
     scene.addSegment(SceneSegment(theEnd, Actions.fadeIn(4f)))

     scene.addSegment(SceneSegment(background, Actions.delay(10f)))
     scene.addSegment(SceneSegment(background, Actions.run { MenuScreen() }))

     scene.start()
}
```

`theEnd` fades in properly, but the `MenuScreen` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the result of calling MenuScreen() as your call back. What does that function return? Perhaps you meant simply MenuScreen, which is a function. Other than that I can't tell what's wrong.